# Of Fighting Fear

Tags: fear, l5r-4e

Recently, our troupe of Samurai was faced with a Yurei, a haunting ghost. It was indeed a powerful one, and it possessed the power of **Fear 3**, sending some of us fleeing and making it nigh impossible to fight. While we managed to retreat to a place that the ghost could not reach, I do wonder:

> Fear effects are given a Rank, ranging from 1 to 10, to represent their severity. To resist a Fear effect, a character must roll Raw Willpower at a TN equal to 5+(5 x Fear Rank). Thus fighting a Fear 3 effect requires a roll at TN 20. Those of high Honor, however, are better able to overcome this test - all characters may add their Honor Rank to the total of their roll. <sup>1</sup>

What means are available to fight or reduce the effects of fear but the Willpower roll + Honor Rank to evade the effect when it starts?

---

1 - Legends of the 5 Rings, Core book 4th Edition, page 90.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are all of the sources I could find to combat fear in the Core, Secrets of the Empire, and Element Books.

### Stances

- Center Stance, if you can take the time, grants +1k1+Void to one roll in the next turn

### Advantages

- The Paragon(Courage) advantage is explicitly +1k1 against fear, plus the extra honor rank
- Friend of the Elements(Earth) advantage is a free raise for Willpower trait rolls
- Virtuous advantage increases starting honor rank
- Luck advantage for the reroll

  - Toku Ancestor (Secrets of the Empire 244) One free rank of Luck
- Seppun Ancestor (Secrets of the Empire 243) One free void point effect per session
- Kaimetsu-Uo Ancestor for +1k1 to Willpower rolls as long as it's not for transcending a taunt

### Schools & Tattoos

- The Mantis tattoo of the Togashi Tattooed Order negates fear
- Shiba Bushi School allows the use of a second void point when using it for +1k1 to a roll
- Temple of Persistence Monk (Book of Earth 205) can ignore all penalties, so that will include a marginally failed fear save
- Seppun Astrologers School (Book of Water 179) to confer a spiritual advantage, e.g. Luck or Friend of Elements above

### Spells

- Courage of the Seven Thunders (Earth 1) is a spell specifically for countering fear (+5k0 for Great Clan, +3k0 anyone else)
- Never Alone (Fire 1) spell is a raw bonus to trait rolls
- Reversal of Fortunes (Water 1) for the reroll
- Drawing the Void (Void 1) for the void points